# Moving a wp multisite to new host - The domain name will be changed but the current one needs to stay as well

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, hosting

I have a WordPress multi site, 1 main domain and 21 additional domains on it. Now I am changing host, Currently I am on just host and moving to go daddy, on go daddy I have a new domain which I want to make the main domain and want to make these 22 domains like sub-domains on it.

A more clearer example here

Site = Abc.com
21 additional domains = abc.net/info/ie/tk/eu/pk/in ..... and so on

I want to move all these without losing any data to a new hosting and domain.
What is the best process I should use this problem is not addressed any where , I searched everywhere , word press forum , stack exchange , Google , I can not get a clear answer of HOW TO DO THIS.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the creation of additional subdomains (.net, .info, .eu), that is something you'd have to do from the provider's side (GoDaddy) as Wordpress cannot create these.

Comment: -_- understand the question 1st , I am moving the site files , I will point the domains through dns as subdomains